# Testing framework for nodejs and angular based client side application

Tags: node.js, frameworks

I am new to nodejs and currently searching for framework to test nodejs and angular based client side application.

I have google and i found that mocha,jasmine etc. various framework available for testing JavaScript.

But can any one explain which framework should i use **to test my nodejs and angular based client side application**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the framework [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/). It's a BSD style testing framework. If you search for testing on the angular site this [article](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) comes up. It suggest using [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor). I know for a fact that several Angular JS tutorials recommend Jasmine and there is a lot of material on testing for Angular using Jasmine.

Either of these frameworks should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha can definitely be used to test both client and server side code, and I'm fairly sure Jasmine can too.

Answer (score 0):

For all of my node testing I use a combination of the following:

- mocha (https://npmjs.org/package/mocha) for a test runner
- chai (https://npmjs.org/package/chai) for an assertion library
- supertest (https://npmjs.org/package/supertest) to test apis.

Some of my other team members used to use jasmine but everyone has since moved from jasmine to mocha.

An example test for apis with this configuration would look like this:

```
var should = require('chai').should();
var request = require('supertest');

describe('your test file description', function(){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080',

    describe("POST: your url", function() {
        it('include useful description of test', function(done){
            request(url)
                .post('/endpoint')
                .set('Accept', 'application/json')
                .set('Accept-Language', 'en_US')
                .send({
                    your : "data"
                })
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    if (err) { throw err; }
                    res.status.should.equal(200);
                    res.body.should.have.property('id');
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```